# Decomposition as a product of factors

Tags: number-theory

For several days, I try to do this excercise. Without success.

Prove that for any pair of positive integers $k$ and $n$, there exist $k$ positive integers $m_1, m_2, \dots, m_k$ (not necessarily different) such that:
$$1+ \frac{2^k - 1}n = \left(1+\frac 1{m_1}\right)\cdot\left(1+\frac 1{m_2}\right)\cdots\left(1+\frac 1{m_k}\right)$$

Comment: do you have any examples where it works?

Comment: it works for k=1 for example.

Comment: have you tried  induction?

Comment: I have tried induction on k. But I can not prove the property to the rank k +1.

Comment: I've worked out $k=2$, for anybody who's curious: for $n$ odd, $(n,\frac{n+1}{2})$ is a solution.  For $n$ even, $(n+2,\frac{n}{2})$ is.  These seems to be more or less unique.

Comment: I tried $k=3$. If $n\equiv-1 \mod 4$ then $m1=n$, $m2=(n+1)/2$, $m3=(n+3)/4$ works.

Comment: @User-33433: For $k=2$ and $n=10$, $1+3/10 = (1+1/4) \cdot (1+1/25)$. For $k=2$ and $n=11$, $1+3/11 = (1+1/4) \cdot (1+1/55)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$k=1$ is clear.  We now suppose that the statement is true for some fixed $k$ (and all $n$), and proceed to demonstrate it for $k+1$.

If $n$ is even, then we can write $1+\frac{2^k-1}{\frac{n}{2}}$ as a product of the given form with $k$ terms.  And so, the following can be written as a product with $k+1$ terms:

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n+2^{k+1}-2}\right)\left(1+\frac{2^k-1}{\frac{n}{2}}\right) = \left(\frac{n+2^{k+1}-1}{n+2^{k+1}-2}\right)\left(\frac{n+2^{k+1}-2}{n}\right)$$
$$= \frac{n+2^{k+1}-1}{n} = 1 + \frac{2^{k+1}-1}{n}$$

This verifies the claim when $n$ is even.  If $n$ is odd, then we can write $1+\frac{2^k-1}{\frac{n+1}{2}}$ as a product with $k$ terms.  As above, the following is a product with $k+1$ terms:

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{2^k-1}{\frac{n+1}{2}}\right) = \left( \frac{n+1}{n}\right)\left( \frac{n+2^{k+1}-1}{n+1}\right)$$
$$= \frac{n+2^{k+1}-1}{n} = 1 + \frac{2^{k+1}-1}{n}$$

That about does it.