# 2013 International Mathematical Olympiad Problem 1

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was looking at the 2013 International Mathematical Olympiad problems and for number 1 I don't think I am understanding the question correctly. For example if you let $k = 2$ and $n = 4$, then I can't figure any two integers $m_1$ and $m_2$ to satisfy the equality. I'm not sure what I am missing here.

Here is a link to the questions and solutions.

http://www.imomath.com/index.php?options=785

Here is the question:
Assume that  $k$  and  $n$  are two positive integers. Prove that there exist positive integers  $m_1 ,  \ldots ,  m_k$  such that
\begin{equation}
1 + \frac{2^k - 1}{n} = \left(1 + \frac{1}{m_1}\right) \cdots \left(1 + \frac{1}{m_k}\right). 
\end{equation}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620111/decomposition-as-a-product-of-factors)

Answer (score 1):

$$1 + \frac{3}{4} = \left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{6}\right)$$

See my full solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/621083/33433).